# Story where an unstoppable machine covers the world with grey matter?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for a short story I read many many years ago. If I remember correctly, the story featured a machine which was unstoppable, possibly because a mechanism to stop it has been lost. The machine produces something like grey dust, which ends up covering the whole planet (and maybe more).

Comment: This is sometimes referred to as a "grey goo" scenario involving nanotechnology. You might check the Literature section of http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GreyGoo at TV Tropes and see if you find a match.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like "The Laxian Key" by Robert Sheckley.

It's about couple of guys that buy a machine runs forever, takes its energy from the air/suroundings (don't remember exactly), and  never breaks down.

They turn the machine on and it starts producing gray powder called Tangreese. They're forced to leave Earth to find a market for this powder, discover the home planet of the machine where everything is covered/build by Tangreese etc.

Comment: This sounds like a solid match.

Comment: This was one of Sheckley's stories about the AAA Ace Decontamination Service which ran in Galaxy in the early '50s.  The two dim protagonists recurrently took on work far beyond their abilities, often relying on equipment bought cheap from Joe the Interstellar Junkman.  In this story, one of them buys the machine from Joe in the hope of finding a use for Tangreese, but it can only be turned off with a Laxian Key, impossible to find.   When they reach the home planet, it's covered pole to pole with Tangreese, with the inhabitants searching the galaxy for a Laxian Key...